# How to setup ZeroMQ on Windows to work with OpenPGM?

Tags: zeromq

How to setup ZeroMQ on Windows to work with OpenPGM?

Answer (score 5):

I've done it.  It wasn't as hard as I originally feared. Here's how I did it:

1. Download OpenPGM binaries from here: http://miru.hk/openpgm/
2. Download ZMQ source, either the tarball or from github
3. Open builds\msvc\msvc10.sln in Visual Studio
4. Select the WithOpenPGM configuration
5. Add appropriate OpenPGM directories to the additional Include directories
6. Add appropriate OpenPGM directories to additional library directories
7. Add appropriate OpenPGM .lib file to additional linker dependencies
8. Build and enjoy

Answer (score 4):

if I remember correctly the snapshots are built with OpenPGM support: http://snapshot.zero.mq/

Answer (score 2):

You first follow the OpenPGM guide: https://code.google.com/p/openpgm/wiki/OpenPgm5CReferenceBuildLibraryWindows then you make sure that the compilation process of zeromq can link that library...

It should be possible to get to work, however, this is possible it's not that easy: 
https://zeromq.jira.com/browse/LIBZMQ-377

However, you can download a completely compiled binary with OpenPGM on Windows from here:
http://www.zeromq.org/distro:microsoft-windows

Answer (score 1):

If I were in your shoes, I would set up OpenPGM on FreeBSD or Ubuntu and have a router process there that takes the messages from the Windows machine and multicasts them. That way, you have a much simpler problem to deal with on Windows, and you will be using one of the preferred platforms for OpenPGM

Almost all the code that you need to handle the routing scenario is already written for you in the 0MQ Guide.